# How to get EVENTVALIDATION?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to simulate a logon into a Asp.Net Webforms page. I am using fiddler to compare the "simulated" login and the real login. The only thing that's missing in my request is a value for __EVENTVALIDATION, but i don't know how to capture the EVENTVALIDATION-variable so i can send it in my request.
My code looks like this:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://myserver.com/Start.aspx?g=36");
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myserver.com/login/Login.aspx");
request1.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
//response1.Cookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream());
string loginPage = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

string viewState = GetViewState(loginPage);
string postback = String.Format("__VIEWSTATE={0}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$UserName={1}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$Password={2}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$LoginButton=Logga in", viewState, "myusername", "mypassword");
HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myserver.com/login/Login.aspx");
request2.Method = "POST";
request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request2.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(postback);
writer.Close();
request2.GetResponse().Close();
```

I need to attach the eventvalidation-field with the last request, but i have no idea of have to capture the value of eventvalidation...